# How to share .kube/config?

Tags: kubernetes

There are multiple admins who accesses k8s clusters.
What is the recommended way to share the config file?

I know,

```
kubectl config view --minify
```

but certification part is REDACTED by this command.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add the --flatten flag, which is described in the [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/25ddd24f9e3ac53a1944e02109db95787c7f1b4a/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_config_view.md) to "flatten the resulting kubeconfig file into self contained output (useful for creating portable kubeconfig files)"

Comment: Thank you! --flatten --minify outputs what I want!!