# Share kube config

Tags: kubernetes

I read this post about how to share kube config.

[How to share .kube/config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34270076/how-to-share-kube-config/34271748#34271748)

It says that `kubectl config view --flatten --minify` is the way to get kube config file.
But when it comes to use this config file, I am confused.
For example, if the output is saved as `config-yuta`, do I always specify the config file like this?
`kubectl --kubeconfig=config-yuta cluster-info`

I feel too troublesome to specify `--kubeconfig=xxx` always.
I just want to switch the context and do like `kubectl cluster-info` without specifying a certain file when I have multiple clusters.

Should I merge ~/.kube/config with the output?
If so, how can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set multiple clusters in the same kubeconfig file, see [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/)

Another solution to use multiple kubeconfig files is to set the environment variable KUBECONFIG

```
export KUBECONFIG=<path to config-yuta>
```

And finally it's also possible to merge the file config-yuta with the default kubeconfig with this command:

```
KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/config:<path to config-yuta> kubectl config view --flatten > ~/.kube/config
```

Comment: I could merge config file in this way.

Comment: :) you're welcome! Please Mark the answer as correct if it fulfills the question requirements